# Small application of Fubini-Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

My books says:

$$
a(r-1,s)=\int_{0}^t dt_1 \int_{0}^t dt_2 ... \int_{0}^t dt_{r-1}1_{\{t_1<t_2<...<t_{r-1}<s\}}=\frac{s^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}
$$

Now I get the part with $s^{r-1}$ but why do they devide by $(r-1)!$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $t\geq s$, we have
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^t dt_{1}1_{\{t_1<t_2<...<t_{r-1}<s\}}
=\int_0^{t_2}dt_1
=t_2\\
&\int_{0}^t dt_{2}\int_{0}^t dt_{1}1_{\{t_1<t_2<...<t_{r-1}<s\}}
=\int_0^{t_3}dt_{2}\,t_2
=\frac{t_3^2}2\\
&\int_{0}^t dt_{3}\int_{0}^t dt_{2}\int_{0}^t dt_{1}1_{\{t_1<t_2<...<t_{r-1}<s\}}
=\int_0^{t_4}dt_{3}\,\frac{t_3^2}2
=\frac{t_4^3}{2\cdot3}\\
&........................................................\\
&\int_{0}^t dt_1 \int_{0}^t dt_2 ... \int_{0}^t dt_{r-1}1_{\{t_1<t_2<...<t_{r-1}<s\}}=\frac{s^{r-1}}{2\cdot 3\cdots(r-1)}.
\end{align}